# VS2012 CodedUI tests - how to publish and run on remote machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have recorded some CodedUI tests in VS2012.

How do I get them to run on a remote machine? (The remote machine already has a test agent configured, connected to a Test Controller).

In my .testsettings file, the dropdown to choose a Test Controller is always blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you've selected "Remote Execution" for your Test Execution method combobox, you should get an option for `<Manage Test Controllers...>` in the Controller combobox.

[image: Test Settings view]

Once you've [configured your controller and agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx) properly, if the controller is on the same network and is running, it should display in this dialog.

[image: After clicking "Manage Test Controllers", this dialog appears.]

Also check that your permissions and that the right user is logged into the remote machine.  For more detailed info, [check out this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182638.aspx)